# Xcode OS/X: How to display results of a core data fetch request in a table view

Tags: macos, core-data, nstableview

I perform a fetch request on a managed object context that is written into an array. The fetch itself works well and the array is filled correctly. However, as I try to display the array contents in a (cell based) table view nothing is displayed. The setup is as follows:

- A `NSArrayControllers` content array is bound to the File's Owner results array (which, as far as I understand, is filled with `NSManagedObject` objects). Here I tried both, entity and class mode.
- The table views content is bound to the array controllers arranged objects.
- The table columns values are bound to the array controller using controller key: arranged object, model key path: properties name (as defined in the data model).

I also created a `NSManagedObject` subclass for my Objects in order to access the properties for the binding in class mode.

None of the above had the table view filled with the results of the fetch request. So, can anyone assist me in getting this correct? Thanks!

As requested, here is the code for the fetch method (everything else is done in the Interface Builder):

```
- (IBAction)fetch:(id)sender {

NSLog(@"Performing fetch.");

NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];

// Connecting entity
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                          entityForName:@"Operation"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:moc];

//Creating fetch request
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];

// Set predicate for fetch request
float maxDurationInMinutes = [durationFetchInput floatValue];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"(durationInMinutes >= %f)", maxDurationInMinutes];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

//Set sort ordering for fetch request
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                    initWithKey:@"durationInMinutes" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
fetchReturnArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:array];

[objectsCountOutput setIntegerValue:[fetchReturnArray count]];
if (array == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Error fetching...");
}
NSLog(@"%@",fetchReturnArray);
}
```

Comment: Provide some code, please.

Comment: done. Thanks for taking a look!